# jQuery autocomplete IntelliJ vs Netbeans

Tags: jquery, netbeans, intellij-idea, autocomplete

I have one question. Why IntelliJ Idea 14 has so bad jQuery plugin autocomplete while Netbeans has great support. Is there any way to force autocomplete behaviour in IntelliJ like Netbeans?

Idea 
  [image: IntelliJ Idea jQuery autocomplete]

Netbeans

[image: Netbeans jQuery autocomplete]

Comment: I didn't use IntelliJ for front-end, so I don't know if it allows what you want to do. You can go to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com > create an account > Create Issue. Usually those issues are assigned in 1-2 days to a person and probably they are fixed according to the received votes. They fixed 1 of 7 issues reported by me in the last 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is IntelliJ being actually **more** thorough. Like many jQuery methods `.post()` is overloaded. The [actual documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) shows that it **could** be the method NetBeans is suggesting, but it could also use the signature `.post([settings])`. This means at the time you requested auto-completion there is no one right answer.

There is hope! Once you start entering parameters to your call IntelliJ will match the appropriate method signature and begin suggesting completion based on that. This may take a moment, depending on your settings.